# Should visualization tools like tableau or looker be used for multi-tenant systems?

Tags: visualization, apache-superset, looker

Visualization tools like tableau, looker, apache superset are not supposed to be used for multi tenant products.
For example. A product with 1000's of users would like analytics on their data. This needs to be secure so company A cannot see other company B visualizations. For this to work these tools need to understand if a user has privileges to view the data. This is usually achieved through cookies after the user has logged in

To ensure data is only accessed by authorized users these third party tools should not be used. Instead sticking to Ruby on Rails with d3js, highcharts etc is the best options. The data can be managed a lot easier through the same authentication methods as you login and so the data is secure.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a real question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Looker handles multi-tenant data situation just fine.  It is quite a common use case for Looker.

You can bind attributes to users that will force the right SQL to be written to guarantee that the user only sees appropriate data.

https://docs.looker.com/reference/explore-params/access_filter

We've got lots of customers building extranets for their businesses this way.

Disclosure: I work at looker.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of multi-tenant deployments goes far beyond the setup of some filter:

- Data privacy - you are one typo away from a data privacy breach with the filters. You should use the database security and privacy capabilities to isolate your tenants.
- Performance - you need to scale the underlying database to handle the load of concurrent users.
- Customization - your tenants might need to load and analyze their own custom data. They need custom reports, etc.

Take a look at gooddata.com and their workspaces.

Disclosure: I work at GoodData